# PL/SQL: What happens to collection contents inside a compound trigger in case of unhandled exception

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

Let's say we have the following trigger:

```
create or replace trigger TR_TEST  
for update or insert or delete  
  on TABLE_X  
compound trigger  
  type array is table of TABLE_X%rowtype index by binary_number;
  recs array;

  before each row is
    i number default rowids.count + 1;
  begin
    recs(i).a := nvl(:NEW.a, :OLD.a);
    recs(i).b := nvl(:NEW.b, :OLD.b);
    recs(i).c := nvl(:NEW.c, :OLD.c);
    recs(i).d := nvl(:NEW.d, :OLD.d);
  end before each row;

  after statement is
  begin
    -- Do procedure here that will throw an exception
  end after statement;

end TR_TEST;
```

When the after statement throws an exception and is unhandled, what will happen to the contents of the array? Will it be automatically cleaned or will remain in memory throughout the session? If the latter is true, what is the proper way to handle it to prevent memory leaks? Thanks!

Comment: It'll be cleaned up when the trigger exits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PL/SQL automatically takes care of variable scope for you, you don't have to worry about it (in fact, there's nothing you can do explicitly about it anyway).

In this case, the array is allocated when the trigger starts (e.g. when the first row is inserted/updated/deleted), and remains until the end of the trigger (i.e. after the after statement section finishes, or when an exception is raised and propogated to the caller).

When the trigger goes out of scope, the array will no longer be accessible, and Oracle may deallocate the memory used for it at some later point at its discretion.

Answer (score -1):

From my knowledge, if there is an exception thrown in a trigger, a rollback is done .

See http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:482821541531 for more info.

Comment: -1, a rollback is irrelevant to this question which is about the collection.

Comment: `When the after statement throws an exception and is unhandled, what will happen to the contents of the array?` if this happens, a rollback is done. so the array will behave accordingly to any other array used when a rollback is performed...or is the case of the trigger more special ?

Comment: Nothing special about triggers. I don't know what you think a rollback does. It only affects DML; it never affects the state of PL/SQL variables.